# Can rest-assured with cucumber be used with spring mvc (version 5)?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cucumber, rest-assured

I m trying to setup BDD tests using cucumber, rest assured and spring 5. I am constantly getting error for weapplicationcontext is required. weapplicationcontext is not getting instantiated. I am using `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build()` still its null.

I have tried to include `@ContextConfiguration` , `@WebAppConfiguration`

```
@Configuration
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
@Import({AppConfig.class, TestConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles({"local", "test"})
public class TestSetup {

    protected WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Given("^the web context is set$")
    public void the_web_context_is_set() {
        //ServletRequest servletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        //AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        //ctx.register(BookkeepingAppConfig.class);
       // ctx.setServletContext(servletRequest.getServletContext());
       // this.webApplicationContext = ctx;
        TestContext.getInstance().setMockMvc(MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build());
    }
```

Comment: You're not autowiring the WAC?

Comment: @mpkorstanje I tried that as well but still no luck.

Comment: To make sure the spring config is correct, have you tried adding `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and replacing `@Given` with `@Test`?

Comment: @mpkorstanje I m trying to use it with cucumber and rest assured.

Comment: Sure. But that wasn't the goal. You have to break this problem into smaller parts first. So you know the indiviual parts work.

Comment: @mpkorstanje I agree.I have tests running with annotation @ Test